# Ubuntu/Debian How to identify USB port of device

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, debian, usb

How can you identify individual USB devices to unbind and bind them? Specifically, devices like mice, keyboard, dongles, etc. which are not storage.

For example, on Debian (Raspbian GNU/Linux v8.0 in this case), I have a few devices listed in /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/:

**ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/** shows USB devices:

```
1-1.2:1.0  1-1.2:1.1  1-1.2:1.2  1-1.3:1.0  1-1.3:1.1  1-1.4:2.2
```

**lsusb** shows:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1410:9020 Novatel Wireless
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsusb -t** shows:

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/5p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_ether, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
```

I know that the **Novatel Wireless** is **1-1.4:2.2** from guessing.

I can then reset it by running **echo -n '1-1.4:2.2' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind** and **echo -n '1-1.4:2.2' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/bind**

It would be great if there was an obvious way to identify it and reset it in a bash script. Also, how can a device be identified and reset if there are more than one of the same hardware on different ports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both pieces of information are in the `/dev` or `/sys/class` directory.

You can use `ls -l /sys/class/xxx`, where `xxx` substitutes the device category you want to query.

`ls -l /sys/class/block`:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host251/target251:0:0/251:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1
```

The problem is that you have to know which device you are looking for, i.e., have a name or bus number. However, you can get this information by `lsusb` or commands used for the specific device class, i.e., `ip link` (an LTE modem is normally implemented as an RNDIS host and shows up in `ip link` as `usb0`), `lsblk --output NAME,KNAME,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,RM,UUID`, ...

For any **USB** device, `ls - l /sys/class/xxx` will output USB port and udev path

Your Novatel Wireless (Ethernet over USB) will be in `sys/class/ǹet`.
You can also identify devices using `vendorid` and `productID`.

If you need more information, you can use `udevadm`:

```
sudo udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk --path=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host251/target251:0:0/251:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1

 looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host237/target237:0:0/237:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1':
    KERNEL=="sdb1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{partition}=="1"
    ATTR{start}=="64"
    ATTR{size}=="62517184"
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{stat}=="     156        7     1304      132        0        0        0        0        0      128      128"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
```

Another possibility is to use run `udevadm monitor`  and then attach the device.

(*https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116664/map-physical-usb-device-path-to-bus-device-number-returned-by-lsusb*, *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74513/udev-how-do-you-identify-the-physical-device-that-a-sys-device-belongs-to*)

For a mouse (input device), try:

```
sudo udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk --name=/dev/input/mouse0
```